# Force a derived class to override one of a set of virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

Given a base class which has some virtual functions, can anyone think of a way to force a derived class to override exactly one of a set of virtual functions, at compile time? Or an alternative formulation of a class hierarchy that achieves the same thing?

In code:

```
struct Base
{
    // Some imaginary syntax to indicate the following are a "pure override set"
    // [
    virtual void function1(int) = 0;
    virtual void function2(float) = 0;
    // ...
    // ]
};

struct Derived1 : Base {}; // ERROR not implemented
struct Derived2 : Base { void function1(int) override; }; // OK
struct Derived3 : Base { void function2(float) override; }; // OK

struct Derived4 : Base // ERROR too many implemented
{
    void function1(int) override;
    void function2(float) override;
};
```

I'm not sure I really have an actual use case for this, but it occurred to me as I was implementing something that loosely follows this pattern and thought it was an interesting question to ponder, if nothing else.

Comment: `Derivedx` are supposed to be further derived by a non-abstract subclass?

Comment: There is no way to do that, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: I know C++ doesn't work like this, the code is just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: illustrate what problem? Do you further derive from the `Derivedxy` classes? How will the concrete classes look like?

Comment: To illustrate the problem as outlined in the post, is something not clear? No, I do not want to further derive.

Comment: but if you dont further derive you wont be able to create instances of `Derivedxy` classes. Or do you also want some "magic" to make `Derivedxy` non-abstract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can fake it.

Base has non-virtual float and int methods that forward to a pure virtual std variant one.

Two helper classes, one int one float, implement the std variant one, forwarding both cases to either a pure virtual int or float implementation.

It is in charge of dealing with the 'wrong type' case.

Derived inherit from one or another helper, and implement only int or float.

```
struct Base
{
    void function1(int x) { vfunction(x); }
    void function2(float x) { vfunction(x); }
    virtual void vfunction(std::variant<int,float>) = 0;
};
struct Helper1:Base {
    void vfunction(std::variant<int,float> v) final {
      if (std::holds_alternative<int>(v))
        function1_impl( std::get<int>(v) );
    }
    virtual void function1_impl(int x) = 0;
};
struct Helper2:Base {
    void vfunction(std::variant<int,float> v) final {
      if (std::holds_alternative<float>(v))
        function2_impl( std::get<float>(v) );
    }
    virtual void function2_impl(float x) = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {}; // ERROR not implemented
struct Derived2 : Helper1 { void function1_impl(int) override; }; // OK
struct Derived3 : Helper2 { void function2_impl(float) override; }; // OK
```

This uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern -- the interface contains non-virtual methods, whose details can be overridden to make them behave differently.

If you are afraid people will override `vfunction` you can use the private lock technique, and/or just give it a name like `private_implementation_detail_do_not_implement` and trust your code review process.

Comment: Cool, that's pretty good. It suppose only really works if the functions in the override set have a similar signature though. e.g. you couldn't have function1(int, int, int) and function2(string) because variant argument of the virtual function can only discriminate a single type. I mean I guess you could use a tuple to represent a parameter pack (variant<tuple<int, int, int>, string>) but it's getting pretty hideous in that case. Anyway, nice.

Comment: @TimAngus I think it is already hideous.  :)  So tuple away!  In any case, `vfunction` isn't actually required: NVI for `function1` can call `virtual function1_private_implementation_detail`, and `Helper1` can override both implementation details, and forward the one you are allowed to use to a `function1_impl`.  The point is `Helper1` implements the **policy** for overriding.

Answer (score 2):

> Or an alternative formulation of a class hierarchy that achieves the same thing?

One option is to have an intermediate base class that implements one function.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void function(int) = 0;
    virtual void function(float) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct TBase : Base
{
   virtual void function(T) override {} 
};

struct Derived1 : Base {};
struct Derived2 : TBase<float> { void function(int) override {} };
struct Derived3 : TBase<int> { void function(float) override {} };

int main()
{
   Derived1 d1; // ERROR. Virtual functions are not implemented
   Derived2 d2; // OK.
   Derived3 d3; // OK.
}
```

Note that the functions are named `function` in this approach, not `function1` and `function2`.

Comment: I like that, certainly for the case where the functions are overloads. At first I thought it would lead to the problem that e.g. d3.function(int) could still be called (to no effect), but of course the inherited overload is name hidden since Derived3 itself overloads function. One possible improvement would be to replace "typename T" with a parameter pack "typename... Args" thus enabling it for overloads that take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes will remain abstract if you don't override all the abstract virtual methods. You have to do all of them if you want to instantiate the object.

Comment: Yes, I know. The pseudocode is just to illustrate the problem.